# Как работать с NtMapViewOfSection?

Tags: windows, ассемблер, native

Кто работал с **NtMapViewOfSection**, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Хочу открыть доступ к физ. памяти (в 2000-XP) по адресам от 0xC0000 до 0x100000.

Вот такой вызов (fasm, т.е. что не в [кв. скобках] - это адрес, а не значение):

```
invoke NtMapViewOfSection, [hPhysMem], -1, BaseAddr, 0, 0, SectionOffset, ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READWRITE
. . .
align 4
SectionOffset dq 0xC0000
BaseAddr dd 0
ViewSize dd 0x40000
hPhysMem rd 1 ; handle of physical memory section
```

выдаёт ошибку 0xC0000005 (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION).

Перед этим выполняется **NtOpenSection** без ошибок. Если **NtMapViewOfSection** заменить на:

```
invoke MapViewOfFile, [hPhysMem], FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0xC0000, 0x40000
```

то всё работает.

И заодно такой вопрос: какие есть ещё способы прочитать физ. память в Windows (по крайней мере, в старых версиях)? Хотя ведь по факту, в то же 7-ке под NTVDM можно адреса 0xC0000..0xFFFFF прочитать же.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку!

Надо просто заменить **PAGE_READWRITE** на **PAGE_READONLY** (хотя я вроде так пробовал, но видимо, не допробовал).